# Expressjs Routing Issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to have a link on my page send a user to the correct blogpost, but I can't seem to figure out how to use my route within my view file. Every time I click on the link, I am given this error:

```
{
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \":blogpost_id\" at path \"_id\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "type": "ObjectId",
  "value": ":blogpost_id",
  "path": "_id"
}
```

Is this the result of how my GET method on the route is set up or how I'm trying to use it within my view?

The url is `localhost:8080/:blogpost_id` which is a incorrect. The "Read More" link is what I'm talking about.

routes.js

```
  var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
var paginate = require('express-paginate');

//index 
router.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));

    router.route('/') 

        // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // set the tags
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // set the date of the post
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({ message: 'Blog created.' });
                });

        }) // END POST method


        // START GET method
        .get(function(req, res, next) {

            Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {

                if (err) return next(err)

                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);

                        blogpost.title = req.body.title; // get the blog title
                        blogpost.author = req.body.author; // get the author name
                        blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // get tagline
                        blogpost.content = req.body.content; // get the blog content
                        blogpost.category = req.body.category; // get the category
                        blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; // get the tags
                        blogpost.date = req.body.date; // get the date of the post

                        res.format({
                            html: function() {
                                res.render('pages/index', {
                                    blogpost: blogpost,
                                    pageCount: pageCount,
                                    itemCount: itemCount
                                })
                            },
                            json: function() {

                                res.json({
                                    object: 'blogpost',
                                    has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                    data: blogpost
                                })
                            }
                        }); // END res.format(html, json)
            }); // END Blogpost.paginate
        }); // END GET method


    //Route for individual blogs
    router.route('/:blogpost_id')

    // START GET method blog by ID  
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blog) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // update the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // update the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // update the category 
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; //update the tags
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // update the date of the post


            res.json(blog);
            res.render('/pages/blogpost');
        });
    }) // END GET method blog by ID

    // START PUT method
    .put(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.findById(req.params.blogpost_id, function(err, blogpost) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);


            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // update the blog title
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // update the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // update the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // update the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // update the category 
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags; //update the tags
            blogpost.date = req.body.date; // update the date of the post


            blogpost.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);


                res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
            });

        });

    }) // END PUT method

    // START DELETE method
    .delete(function(req, res) {

        Blogpost.remove({
            _id: req.params.blogpost_id

        }, function(err, bear) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
        });
    });



//about
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
            res.render('pages/about');
    });


module.exports = router;
```

index.ejs

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div class="blog-content">
                <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h2><a href="#" class="blog-title"><%= blogpost.title %></a></h2></td>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-category"><%= blogpost.category %></h3>
                        <td><h3 class="blog-tagline"><i><%= blogpost.tagline %></i></h3></td>
                        <td><p><%= blogpost.content %></p></td>
                        <td><a href="<%= /:blogpost_id %>" class="blog-read-more">Read More</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="paginate">
        <% include ../partials/paginate %>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this line

```
<a href="<%= /:blogpost_id %>" class="blog-read-more">Read More</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="/<%= blogpost.id %>" class="blog-read-more">Read More</a>
```

in order to use the id of the blog post in the `forEach` loop. You might need to add the ids of blog posts to the data sent to the view, the route is not shown in the question.

Comment: Hey @Russ Cam, sorry I didn't notice I left out part of the route file. See above for edited routes file. I originally used a `forEach` loop for the blog routing, but it was preventing my pagination from working. I'm assuming that by leaving out the loop is the reason why this isn't working. Would you agree?

Comment: You have two GET routes related to blog posts, `"/"` which returns a collection (page) of blog posts and `"/:blogpost_id"` which returns the blog post whose id matches the value of `:blogpost_id` in the route parameters. The `forEach` is used to iterate over the blog posts in the view, so for each blog post, the Read More link should be using the id of the blog post. It looks like your `"/"` is trying to work with one blog post when it should be working with a collection of blog posts as per the express js paginate example here https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate